# Why would this PHP be causing an execution timeout?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've just released the first version of a WordPress plugin I wrote, and I've received a report that at least one of the people using my plugin is receiving an execution timeout error citing this block of code:

```
function getNumericAttributeFromHTML($htmlElement, $attribute){
    $attrStartPos = stripos($htmlElement, $attribute) + strlen($attribute);

    $strOffset = 0;
    $searchWithin = substr($htmlElement, $attrStartPos);

    while(!(is_numeric($searchWithin[$strOffset]))){
        $strOffset++;
    }
    $attrStartPos += $strOffset;

    $strOffset = 0;
    $searchWithin = substr($htmlElement, $attrStartPos);

    while((is_numeric($searchWithin[$strOffset]))){
        $strOffset++;
    }

    return substr($htmlElement, $attrStartPos, $strOffset);
}
```

This function is called twice per image on the page. Am I being crazy inefficient, or is it possible their host is just terrible?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you show examples of `$htmlElement`, and `$attribute` when it timesout ?

Comment: any reason you're doing things this way instead of a bit of DOM to directly extract an attribute then pass the whole retrieved 'text' to is_numeric?

Comment: Maybe this would be better solved with regular expressions. What exactly is the function supposed to be doing? Getting the value of an attribute whose name is `$attribute`?

Comment: @MarcB I'm a bit of a PHP newb, so I wasn't quite sure how to do that. Aside from that, the plugin is awfully small, and I didn't want to add too much complication into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite `while` loop. You're just incrementing the value of `$strOffset` without changing the value of `$searchWithin[$strOffset]` so if it's not numeric, it never will be and will get stuck looping forever.

Comment: is_numeric() on undefined values is false, so once you run off the end of the string, it automatically terminates.

Comment: I suppose assuming the person has valid HTML might be too much, but assuming that, the value would have to turn non-numeric at some point, even if it's at the end of the string, right?

Comment: @MarcB but the condition is while not is_numeric. So if it returns false, that's going to be while not false, or `while(true) {$strOffset++}` and there is your infinite loop.

Comment: ah yeah. silly me. remind me to go scrub my glasses with windex later on.

Comment: Ah... good call, @AlienWebguy. I'll find another way to do that piece!

Answer (score 2):

`while(!(is_numeric($searchWithin[$strOffset])))` will **run infinte times** if `$searchWithin` has no numeric character!

Note the problem might be somewhere else.

To pinpoint the actual problem I suggest you get the reproducible steps from the bug and use a [profiler](http://xdebug.org) to profile the code. You'll surely find where the problem is.

Comment: Perfect answer, but I saw the marked response first. Thank you so much for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

If its causing timeout, well you have a extra large or infinite loop. You have 2 loops here, check if they are infinite.

If this is not the problem, increase the maximum execution time by adding this at start of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000); //3600 seconds = 1 hour
```